# How do i get back the windows package manager back on the settings . Now I am not able to use winget . Im not able to figure what happened

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, package-managers, winget, windows-package-manager

[image: Screen shot of winget upgrade command and the results are hereHere is screen shot of missing windows package manager app missing from my settings]

I tried winget source reset --force
winget source update --force command

but then again the winget upgrade command is showing
"Failed in attempting to update the source: winget"
"Failed when searching source; results will not be included: winget"

Comment: (re-)install it from msstore?  The app is named "App Installer"  (more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/ )

Comment: Yeah ive tried that too it doesent even show the "get" button nor the"update" button on the microsoft app store .

Comment: The Thing is on running the `winget upgrade` it says ""Failed in attempting to update the source: winget" "Failed when searching source; results will not be included: winget""

Comment: Can you add the contents of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json` to your question?  (as text, not as image)   (This file is mentioned here: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/blob/master/doc/Settings.md )

Comment: BTW: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)  the give screenshot only contains text, which is better readable as text.

Comment: Looks to be a CDN issue - https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/2666

Comment: This was the text present in the file you asked above `{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/winget-settings.schema.json",

    // For documentation on these settings, see: https://aka.ms/winget-settings
    // "source": {
    //    "autoUpdateIntervalInMinutes": 5
    // },
}` .by the way the comments were al ready present

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the CDN for WinGet serving a 0-byte file. The issue should be resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Re-Install Microsoft.AppInstaller, the problem will be solved.
Download the installer file (MSIXBUNDLE) from: https://aka.ms/getwinget